# create xslt to merge duplicate term properties and then delete

Tags: xslt, duplicates

apologies if this is answered elsewhere, I did look at the related questions but couldn't see how they related to this.

I have a file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Zthes>
  <term>
    <termId>1</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Science, Biological</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>OMITERM9998</termId>
      <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    </relation>
  </term>
  <term>
    <termId>2</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Sciences, Biological</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>OMITERMO9999</termId>
      <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    </relation>
  </term>
  <term>
    <termId>OMITERMO9998</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    <termType>Pt</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
   </term>
  <term>
    <termId>OMITERMO9999</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    <termType>Pt</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
   </term>
</Zthes>
```

Is it possible to write a xlst which goes through and merges all Pts?  That would result, in this instance, there would be 2nd term names using the same Pt term.  The id they use is not important.  Every Nd will reference a Pt, not every Pt will have NDs referencing it, and Pts can have multiple Nds referencing them

Thanks for any pointers I am hopeless at these things!

Edit:  the output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Zthes>
  <term>
    <termId>1</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Science, Biological</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>OMITERM9998</termId>
      <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    </relation>
  </term>
  <term>
    <termId>2</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Sciences, Biological</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>OMITERMO9998</termId>
      <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    </relation>
  </term>
  <term>
    <termId>OMITERMO9998</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    <termType>Pt</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
   </term>
      </Zthes>
```

so that the relationship which 2 Nd terms had with 2 Pt terms with the same name, but different IDs, were combined into 2 Nd terms having a relationship with just one Pt term.  As long as the relationships were merged into the first PT, the second PT could be deleted so that there would be no duplicates but the relationships would still be intact?

Comment: Your explanation isn't clear for me. An exact desired output for this input sample would help.

Comment: @Alrejandro hopefully the edit clears it up, many thanks indeed

Comment: Kenny, what identifies the `term` elements with `termType` "Nd" that you want to merge? Is that the `termName` element contents?

Comment: Hi Martin, that's right, the Nds are just referenced by the fact they have termtype nd.  They will also have a relationship to a PT. There are 2 different types of terms, preferred and non preferred.  The non preferred terms reference a preferred term.  Preferred terms are Pts and non preferred terms are Nds.  Its the Pts which need merging, there should be no duplicate Nds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="k1" match="term[termType = 'Pt']" use="termName"/>
<xsl:key name="k2" match="term[termType = 'Pt']" use="termId"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="term[termType = 'Pt'][not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('k1', termName)[1]))]"/>

<xsl:template match="term[termType = 'Nd']/relation/termId">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', key('k2', .)/termName)[1]/termId"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Zthes>
  <term>
    <termId>1</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Science, Biological</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>OMITERM9998</termId>
      <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    </relation>
  </term>
  <term>
    <termId>2</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Sciences, Biological</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>OMITERMO9999</termId>
      <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    </relation>
  </term>
  <term>
    <termId>OMITERMO9998</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    <termType>Pt</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
   </term>
  <term>
    <termId>OMITERMO9999</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    <termType>Pt</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
   </term>
</Zthes>
```

the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Zthes>
  <term>
    <termId>1</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Science, Biological</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId/>
      <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    </relation>
  </term>
  <term>
    <termId>2</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Sciences, Biological</termName>
    <termType>Nd</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
    <relation>
      <relationType>USE</relationType>
      <termId>OMITERMO9998</termId>
      <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    </relation>
  </term>
  <term>
    <termId>OMITERMO9998</termId>
    <termUpdate>Add</termUpdate>
    <termName>Biological Sciences</termName>
    <termType>Pt</termType>
    <termStatus>Active</termStatus>
    <termApproval>Approved</termApproval>
    <termCreatedDate>20110414T07:23:26</termCreatedDate>
    <termCreatedBy>admin</termCreatedBy>
    <termModifiedDate>20110414T07:35:54</termModifiedDate>
    <termModifiedBy>admin</termModifiedBy>
      <termAttribute label="A-Z Entry"/>
   </term>

</Zthes>
```

so one cross reference is not resolved correctly but I think the problem is not with the XSLT but with your data where you have `<termId>OMITERM9998</termId>` but then `<termId>OMITERMO9998</termId>` with a leading `0`. Does that help? Are the ids in the real data in better shape? Or do you need to code to strip leading zeros somehow to match/cross reference elements?

Comment: Hi there, I ran this on a sample bit of code and yes it worked perfectly.  I am not sure what was up with the 0 up there, wonky fingers I hope.  thanks so much, you have been amazing help!